# JPA calling function in a native query is sending multiple parameters instead a UUID Collection

Tags: java, postgresql, function, jpa

I created a PostgreSQL function to get some data from an array of UUID.

i.e:

```
create function journey_statistics(journey_ids uuid[])
returns TABLE(project_id uuid, project_name character varying,...)
language plpgsql
```

If I run the next sql statement it returns the expected data:

```
select * from journey_statistics(array['0f36c7a5-04eb-4329-8e93-a13625a4ffa6'::uuid, 'bc10ee72-7b7f-4bbd-a70a-75477b484d58'::uuid])
```

But then, when I implement it on Java and run it. I am getting the next error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: function journey_statistics(uuid, uuid) does not exist

Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is the native query I am using to call it. And I have used same in other similar functions with no errors. So I can not understand what is the issue or what I am doing wrong.

```
@Query(value = "select cast(project_id as varchar(36)) as projectId, project_name as projectName, cast(project_leader as varchar(36)) as projectLeader" +
        " from journey_statistics(:uuids)", nativeQuery = true)
Collection<JourneyStatisticsView> getJourneyStatisticsById(Collection<UUID> uuids);
```

I have tried to cast data to an array but it looks it is transform to a record[] array.
But more strange is if I pass a Collection of Strings and then I try to cast them I get

> function journey_statistics(character varying, character varying) does not exist

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you change the input data type to the Java method from `Collection<UUID>` to `UUID[]`?

Comment: Thanks @Kaan for the suggestion. Unfortunatelly I am getting the next error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function journey_statistics(bytea) does not exist.

I made a mistake exposing the issue above. So I'll fix it.

When I pass a Collection<String> I am getting next error:
function journey_statistics(character varying, character varying) does not exist.

So I'm thinking probably is some kind of bug.

Comment: Have you tried journey_statistics(array[:uuids]) ?

Comment: Hi @cdr89, thanks for sharing. I have tried so much things and I don't remember all of them. Anyway I have checked just in case and I'm getting this error:
ERROR: function journey_statistics(record[]) does not exist

Comment: JPA uses JDBC, which cannot take a collection as a parameter, and you don’t have a mechanism to turn UUID[] or Collection<UUID> into something the driver and database understands for your procedure’s uuid[]. UUID is not a jdbc type.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, Currently it looks JDBC supports UUID Collections as I have multiple methods using a Collection<UUID> and they are working fine. So I think the issue is when adding a collection into a procedure. 
Select * from journeys where id in :uuids, it works properly. 
Probably I should focus on find how to pass a collection to the procedure.

Comment: I could be mistaken but JDBC does not support java.util.Collection. JPA though might be taking that collection and adding each element as a separate parameter converting "in (:collection)" to "in (?, ?, ?)". You should be able use db arrays for data following something like https://itnext.io/how-to-map-postgresql-array-type-to-list-using-jpa-and-eclipselink-b4e25ca13490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to pass the Collection into the function.

It is not as sophisticated as I wanted. But at least it works.

Basically, I have created a new Repository to use the entity manager and create my own sql statement.

```
@Repository
public class JourneyStatisticsCustomRepositoryImpl implements JourneyStatisticCustomRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List getJourneyStatisticsByIds(Collection<UUID> uuids) {
    final Collection<String> formattedUUID = uuids.stream().map(uuid -> "cast('" + uuid + "' as uuid)").collect(Collectors.toSet());
    final String joinedUUIDs = Strings.join(formattedUUID.iterator(), ',');
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery("select cast(project_id as varchar(36)) as projectId, ..." +
            "... from journey_statistics(array[" + joinedUUIDs +"])", JourneyStatisticsView.class).getResultList();
}
```

This sends the proper collection to the function and returns the data as expected.

Hope this could help someone else with similar issues.